# Negligible set of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

We say that a set $A \subset H$ of a (separable) Hilbert space is negligible if:

> for every orthonormal basis $e_n \in H$ and every sequence $\epsilon_n \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, if $C:= \prod_n [-\epsilon_n e_n, \epsilon_n e_n]$ and $\nu$ denotes the product measure associated to $dx/2\epsilon_n$, then $\nu((H\backslash A) \cap C)=0$.

I saw this in an old thesis that I can't find anymore.  Could someone explain the statement

> $\nu$ denotes the product measure associated to $dx/2\epsilon_n$, then $\nu((H\backslash A) \cap C)=0$

i.e., how exactly does the $\nu$ look like? I don't understand the $dx/2{\epsilon_n}$ part.

Does anyone have any more information or other terms that this concept is called?

Comment: IMHO: I don't think this is a very useful concept. There is no analogue of the Lebesgue measure on Hilbert space, so there is no intrinsic concept of "null set" either.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: I don't know much about what 25Chars is asking, but there are quite a few "notions of nullness" that can be used in a separable Hilbert space, such as Haar null, Gaussian null, cube null, Aronszajn null, $\sigma$-directionally porous, Haar meager, etc. The notion being defined looks like it might be (or might be related to) the notion *Aronszajn null*.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Thank you for the insight!